# Physics Rocket Problem

Tags: definite-integrals, physics

I was working on a problem that asks me to give a definite integral for the energy required to lift a 1-kg payload from earth to the moon via rocket. The background information I am given states that: the distance from the earth to the moon is 362,570 km, earth's surface is 6,371 km from it's center, along with the equations: $$E=F*r$$ and $$F(r)= k/r^2$$

I set up my integral as this:
$$\int_{6371000}^{362570000} (\frac{9.8}{r^2})r \,dr$$
and was told my function  is wrong, but not why it is wrong. I know the units are off, if I'm trying to end in Joules. What I was thinking is that my integral should be: $$\int_{6371000}^{362570000} (\frac{9.8}{r^2})F \,dr$$
Where F is force. The issue then would be where would acceleration come from if it's not explicitly stated in the problem?

Comment: I think this is not a math problem as much as a physics . The universal  gravitational law states $F=\frac{Gm_1M_2}{r^2}$. Where $G$ is the universal gravitational constant. $m_1,M_2$ are two masses. That's your function take $M_2$ to be the mass of the earth, $m_1=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\mrm{G}}$ and $\ds{\mrm{M}}$ are the *Gravitational Constant* and the *Earth Mass*, respectively.
>   
>   $\ds{\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
> \ds{\mrm{R_{\oplus}}\mbox{: Earth Radius} =} & \ds{6371.0088\ \mbox{Km}} 
> \\[2mm]
> \ds{\mrm{GM \over R_{\oplus}^{2}} = g =} & \ds{9.8\ \mrm{m \over sec^{2}}} 
> \\[2mm]
> \ds{\mrm{d_{EM}:}\mbox{ Distance Earth-Moon} =} & \ds{384400\ \mbox{Km}} 
> \\[2mm]
> \ds{\mrm{m} =} & \ds{1\ \mbox{Kg}} 
> \end{array}\right.}$

\begin{align}
\Delta\varepsilon & =
\int_{\mrm{R_{\oplus}}}^{\mrm{R_{\oplus} + d_{EM}}}
{\mrm{GMm} \over r^{2}}\,\dd r =
\mrm{GMm \over R_{\oplus}} - \mrm{GMm \over R_{\oplus} + d_{EM}} =
\mrm{m{GM \over R_{\oplus}^{2}}\,R_{\oplus}} - \mrm{m\,{GMm \over R_{\oplus}^{2}}\,{R_{\oplus}^{2} \over R_{\oplus} + d_{EM}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\mrm{mgR_{\oplus}\pars{1 - {R_{\oplus} \over R_{\oplus} + d_{EM}}}} =
\mrm{mg\,{1 \over 1 + R_{\oplus}/d_{EM}}\,R_{\oplus}}
\\[5mm] & =
\mrm{1\ Kg\pars{9.8\ {m \over sec^{2}}}\,{1 \over 1 + 6371.0088/384400}\,6371008.8\ m} \approx 
\bbx{\ds{6.1418 \times 10^{7}\ \mbox{Joule}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

The units being wrong is a big clue.  The force is proportional to $\frac 1{r^2}$ as you say.  The force at the surface is $9.8N$.  You need to scale your force to the radius at the surface, so $F=9.8 (\frac {6371^2}{r^2})$  The quantity in parentheses is dimensionless, so the force comes out in Newtons as you want.  For your integral, you need to decide the units of $r$.  If you want the work in joules, those are Newton-meters, so $r$ needs to be in meters.  That impacts the constants you have in kilometers.